# Highcharts wont plot second graph

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, highcharts, webforms

I am plotting multiple graphs and those have to be assigned dynamically. I mean i create divs for graphs dynamically in asp.net. From server side, I supply data for graphs. I try to draw it but only one graph shows.

Here is my function:

```
$s = jQuery.noConflict();
$s(document).ready(function () {
var data = null;
$s('#download').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CanView.aspx/GetGraphData",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (myresult) {
            // put result of method call into txtResult
            // ajax data is ALWAYS ".d" - its a asp.net thing!!!
            //data.push(myresult.d);
            data = myresult.d;
            console.log("Uspjesno");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
            alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
        }
    });
});

$s('#crtaj').click(function () {
    alert("usao je");



    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
        for (var name in data[i]) {
            chart = Highcharts.chart('MainContent_'+name, {

                chart: {
                },

                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
                },

                series: [{
                    data: data[0][name]
                }]
            });
        };
        }
    }

);
});
```

This xAxis should be same for both graphs, because this is just for testing, I will supply data for this later.

**UPDATE**
I forgot to add this update, but there is no problem with highcharts part. The problem was in assigning data. Instead of data[0][name] there should be data[i][name]. Simple mistake that took several hours.

Comment: Hi @narutouzumaki 99, I've tried to reproduce the problem in: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/th61guo9/ but everything seems to work as expected. Could you adapt the example to show the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help, sorry for not posting update sooner.